# Calculating the sum of two numbers with a for in loop

Tags: swift, for-in-loop

i'm extremely new to swift but i have previous experience through college in other programming languages so im familiar with the logistics. however my college professor asked us to do something rather weird that i would have used an Array for, and without one i have no clue how to do what he is asking.

The question is as states:

Create a closure that accepts two Ints and returns an Int (the sum of both int's provided)

but to retrieve the sum, you are supposed to use a For-In Loop?

any help or even a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

my current code to solve this issue is something extremely simple.

```
var returnSum = { (a: Int, b: Int) -> Int in
var sum: Int
sum = (one + two)
return sum
}
```

But i feel like if i hand that in im going to be getting a one very bad mark.

Thank you!

Comment: A loop makes no sense with the given code. And you can replace the three lines in the closure body simply with `return a + b`

Comment: i completely agree with you thats how i ended up here lol. & thank you i'll replace that line

Comment: Only your professor can explain exactly what they meant. Anything from a Stack Overflow user would be just their opinion.

Comment: Yea as a fellow college kid I would clarify with your prof - sounds like a communication error

Comment: `for x in [a,b]`

Answer (score 2):

The code can simply be written as,

```
var returnSum = { $0 + $1 }
```

And since there is nothing sequence like here, a loop makes no sense.